# procmail is not executing scripts correctly

Tags: linux, scripting, centos, procmail

I'm having a strange issue with running scripts (perl and ruby failing) from incoming mail locally delivered by procmail.

The system is CentOS 5.5 with postfix as my mailer, then a .forward set up to send email on to procmail.  The .procmailrc and scripts are identical to a working setup on an Ubuntu server.

Here's the .procmailrc:

```
PATH= /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir
DEFAULT=${MAILDIR}/
LOGABSTRACT=yes
LOGFILE=$HOME/Maildir/proclog
VERBOSE=YES

:0 wc
* ^To.*web@mydomain.com
| /home/web/perltest.pl
```

Here's the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

system("touch /home/web/touchedfile");
```

And then the failure in the log upon receiving email:

```
procmail: Executing "/home/web/perltest.pl"
/home/web/perltest.pl: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"touch /home/web/touchedfile"'
/home/web/perltest.pl: line 3: `system("touch /home/web/touchedfile");'
```

The line endings are all UNIX.  The script runs fine from the command line.

The whole setup works fine if I pipe to procmail directly from the command line, but when it's invoked as part of the local delivery process, the #! line seems to be ignored in the script.

I can get the perl script to run if I explicitly execute perl in the pipe, like so:

```
:0 wc
* ^To.*web@mydomain.com
| perl /home/web/perltest.pl
```

... but I really don't want to admit defeat and do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is selinux, if you turn that off it should work.  I'm not sure how to fix it with selinux enabled.

Here's a way to fix it and still have selinux running. Run `chcon system_u:object_r:procmail_exec_t` on your perl or ruby scripts.  I've verified that is a fix, but I'm not familiar enough with selinux to be sure it's the "correct" fix.

Comment: SELinux was indeed the culprit!  Thank you!